# Delegate Method Signatures in Obj-C, Understanding what their C# equivalents would be

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning Objective C.  I am trying to find the equivalent to method signatures in C#.

I'm confused with the following signatures of a UIViewControllerDelegate

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
```

So, in C# this would be the equivalent of 2 methods names splitViewController with different overloaded signatures?

It's confusing, because the methods are very descriptive...

Take the first example:

splitViewController is name of the method, vc and orientation are the arguments that we pass into it.  shouldHideViewController and inOrientation are the names of the arguments as they are declared in the UISplitViewDelegate .h declaration.

Am, I right with this?  Trying to just confirm that I am learning correctly and I get the concepts here.

When people refer to he first method, they refer to it as splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation
This is weird to me coming from C# as we would just refer to a method solely by the method name and understand it has multiple overloads.  Plus in Obj-C these different "overloads" do handle different things entirely, which is a strage paradigm for me.

Any thoughts...

Comment: afaik the "signature" in objc is the entire "selector" (splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation) which is the only way to recognize the code that's called: there's no overloading in the same sense there's in other langs, so you need to explicit the whole selector to identify the "method" that will be called.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (BOOL) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc 
    shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc 
               inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

Name of the method: `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:`.
Name of the arguments: `svc`, `vc`, `orientation`.

Objective-C doesn't have method overloading. Your code shows two different methods.

> in Obj-C these different "overloads" do handle different things
>   entirely, which is a strage paradigm for me.

The paradigm here is **delegation**, which is a way to extend the behavior of a class by relying on another.

Consider this imaginary API:

```
@interface TableDelegate
-(CGFloat)heightForRow:(NSUInteger)row;
@end

@interface Table
@property (weak) id<TableDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

That is a table object with a delegate property. When the table is being built, it will ask the delegate what should be the height of each row.

```
@interface Controller <TableDelegate>{
    Table _table;
}
@end

@implementation Controller
-(instancetype)init {
    if (self=[super init]){
        _table = [Table new];
        _table.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
-(CGFloat)heightForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
  return 10.f;
}
@end
```

That is a controller that manages a table object. It declares itself as conformant with the protocol  and sets itself as delegate of the table. Now you can add whatever logic you see fit to return the height for a given row (in the example it returns a fixed value).

We didn't have to subclass and we can implement only the delegate methods we are interested on.